# Basic PHP MySQL array grouping question

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

Quick question, which I think has a very easy solution for someone who has anything above the most rudimentary knowledge of PHP/MySQL as I do.

I have a list of cities in a variety of states stored in a database with city, state and some other variables. Right now they get pulled as a list sorted by city name:

- Anchorage, AK
- Baltimore, MD
- Chicago, IL
  etc etc.

I want to be able to group by state first, then list all the cities that have that state value. So it'd look like:

AK

- Anchorage
- Juneau

CA

- Los Angeles
- San Diego
- San Francisco
- etc etc

I know I need to do some sort of foreach and have searched online, but haven't found an example that I can get to work.

Here's what I have to pull the basic list:

```
  $list = mysql_query("SELECT id, alphaname, state FROM regional ORDER BY alphaname",$db);

while ($thearray = mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
  echo "<li><a href='info.html?id=$thearray[id]'>$thearray[alphaname], $thearray[state]</a></li>";
  }
```

The only real way I know how to do it would be to run a query for each state which would be a pain and totally stupid...

Thanks for any help!

**Update** - solved. I went with rockacola's approach though i-g's worked as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this..

Query all city with state, order by state first then by city:

```
SELECT id, alphaname, state 
FROM regional 
ORDER BY state ASC, alphaname ASC
```

Organise your dataset into 2 dimension array:

```
$states = array();
while($thearray = mysql_fetch_array($list)) 
{
    $states[$thearray[state]][$thearray[id]] = $thearray[alphaname];
}
```

Now contents of your `$states` should look something like:

```
Array
(
    [AK] => Array (
        [id_1] = Anchorage
        [id_2] = Juneau
    )
    [CA] => Array (
        [id_3] = Los Angeles
        [id_4] = San Diego
        [id_5] = San Francisco
    )
)
```

Generate your HTML presentation:

*NOTE: Add anchor to reflect proposed question.*

```
foreach($states as $state_name => $cities)
{
    echo '<h3>'.$state_name.'</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($cities as $id => $city_name)
    {
        echo '<li><a href="info.html?id='.$id.'">'.$city_name.'</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: I like this approach better than i-g's because it separates out the presentation from the data retrieval & munging better, but I don't think $tharray[id] is going to have anything in it because your select statement only asks for the name and the state. Still you could just use 

    $states[$thearray[state]][] = $thearray[alphaname]; and leave the IDs out of it.

(In terms of output, one could make a case for using a list of lists as i-g has done.)

Comment: @sprugman, thanks for the correction. I should SELECT id from the query, as ID usage is part of @Voodoo's requirement. and Yes, `$states[$thearray[state]][]` would also work to leave IDs out of it.

Comment: @sprugmanI was using ID as a variable to create links so I did include it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your SQL query to use:

```
ORDER BY state, alphaname
```

This will make your database return results as:

```
state   city
------------------
AK      Anchorage
AK      Juneau
```

...assuming using `SELECT state, alphaname AS city` for the purposes of an example.

The presentation has to be handled in PHP:

```
//Please excuse my hideous attempt at PHP.  Better to think of it as Psuedo code
while ($thearray = mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
  echo $thearray[state]
  echo "<li><a href='info.html?id=$thearray[id]'>$thearray[alphaname]</a></li>";
}
```

...or you could look at `i-g`'s post.

Comment: yep, i would recommend this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

Sort all rows by state. Then, traverse all rows in order. On the first row, and on any row that has a different state than the previous row, output the state name before you output the city name.

Answer (score -2):

SQL won't return more than 2 dimensional data. What you want is to get some kind of pivot column. The answer to your problem is to fetch all rows with:

```
SELECT * FROM regional ORDER BY state;
```

Then sort and group using PHP (or your language of choice), but no SQL.

Comment: Nothing to do with pivoting data, and your `ORDER BY` is identical to what the OP provided.